# Angularjs search results displays empty list when user clear search box

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an angularjs project with ionic where i provide a search bar where users can search for items. The search works perfectly but the issue with the search is when a user inputs the cursor in the search textbox and inputs some names and the desired results is displayed, when the user decides to clear the search and make the box empty, it automatically displayeds 4 empty lists in the HTML.

PHP

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $objData = json_decode($data);

        $key =  $objData->data;
        if(!empty($key)){

            $sql = "SELECT profile_id,fname,lname,RTRIM(profile_pix)as profile_pic from users where CONCAT (fname,lname)LIKE '%$key%' ";

            $result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
            $output = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $output[] = $row;
             }
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
```

JS

```
.controller('SearchController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.url = 'http://localhost/dbapp/templates/search/search.php'; // the get request page
    $scope.search = function (data){

        //create the http post request
        //the data holds the search key
        //the request is a json request
        $http.post($scope.url,
        {"data":$scope.keybords}
                ).success(function (data, status){
                    $scope.status = status;
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.result = data;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                }).error(function (data, status){
                    $scope.data = data || "Request Failed";
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<ion-view>
 <ion-content ng-controller="SearchController" overflow-scroll="false" >

     <div class="item-input-inset bar-light">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" ng-model="keybords" ng-keyup="search()" class="input-medium form-control search-query searchbox" 
            placeholder="Search" | limitTo:20 />
        </label>

     </div>
      <div ng-repeat="res in result track by $index">
      <div class="list">
    <a class="item item-avatar" href="#/tab/search/{{res.profile_id}}/{{profile_id}}">
      <img  class="line_photo_placeholder" src="http://localhost/db/resize_image/image.php?image={{res.profile_pix}}&new_width=200&new_height=200">
      <h2>{{res.fname}} {{res.lname}}</h2>
      <p>{{res.country}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
</div>

     </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: does your users table contains any null value??

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT_WS`

```
CONCAT_WS('',fname,lname)
```

CONCAT_WS is safe when you have fields with a NULL. CONCAT will return NULL if any of the concatenated field is a null.

Comment: i still get null returns

Comment: does your users table contains any null value?

Comment: there is a high possibility cos the records are over 1000

Comment: Create a query to sort out the null field

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have some data in the list before searching for data. And when the user clears his search, the list is empty?

If that is the case, then you will have to handle the following in your search function:

```
$scope.search = function (data){

    //create the http post request
    //the data holds the search key
    //the request is a json request


    // If searchbar is empty
    if (!data) {
        // get the original list
    }
    if (data) {
        $http.post($scope.url, {"data":$scope.keybords})
            .success(function (data, status){
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.result = data;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request Failed";
                $scope.status = status;
            });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the input value by passing model to your function,if the model contains any value then only call your api if it is null simply make a return or do what ever you want like this

```
ng-model="keybords" ng-keyup="search(keybords)"
```

i made a small [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pbjAS8jPkRMCcdryIktK?p=preview) by alerting data  with condition,you can check with by entering and deleting data